# Custom taxonomy query not working with switch_to_blog

Tags: custom-taxonomy, multisite, query, tax-query

Whats the wrong with this query?

```
   $args = array(
   'category__not_in' => 1,
   'post_status' => 'publish',
    'numberposts' => 1,
   'tax_query' => array(
               array(
                   'taxonomy' => 'my-custom-query',
                   'field'    => 'name', // slug = name, but also dont working
                'terms' => array ( '257' ) // simple number (dont ID)
               )
                   )
   );
   $my_posts_by_meta = get_posts($args);
   if( $my_posts_by_meta ) :
       $clone_ID = $my_posts_by_meta[0]->ID;
   else :
       $clone_ID = 'Error Here';
   endif;
```

If I use this, this works...:

```
   $terms = get_the_terms( $original_post_id, 'my-custom-query');
   foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       $termID[] = $term->name;
   }
   echo 'What I want: ' . $termID[0] . '</br>';
```

Whats the problem with the first code? When I use custom_postmeta with the same code (or I dont use the custom taxonomy), works...

Comment: there are some attributes inside, that are invalid (year, month, day, hour, minute, second), plus nobody knows, how you define your $original_author variable. try to strip them all off and see, if you get closer to your goal.. tax_query itself looks good to me..

Comment: I edited my question... The code still not working...

Comment: and you want the query for `POST`s correct? have you tried [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) in favor of `get_posts`?

Comment: I tested now, with WP_Query working... The fault is sure in the code in my question, but I dont now where and why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the solution: [Tax_query not working on multisite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/284514/tax-query-not-working-on-multisite)

(I dont say, that I work with switch_to_blog, because everything is works fine with this function... everything, including postmeta queries, category__not_in, etc., but EXCEPT: tax_query)

So, "you have to register that custom taxonomy in both blogs".  <-- so the problem originate from the different themes, when in the current used theme not registered the custom taxonomy. [BUT, DONT NEED TO ADD TERMS TO THIS TAX, only register]